# Characterize subdifferential of a convex function by directional derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

---

Let $A$ be a subset of a normed space $X$ and $f:A \to \mathbb R$.

- Let $a \in \operatorname{int} A$. For $v \in X$, the *right directional* derivative $f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$, the *left directional* derivative $f_{-}^{\prime}(a)[v]$, and the (*bilateral*) directional derivative $f^{\prime}(a)[v]$ are defined by:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t} \\
  f_{-}^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0^-} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t} \\
  f^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t}.
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  We say that $f$ is *Gâteaux differentiable* at $a$ if $f^{\prime}(a) \in X^{*}$.
- The *subdifferential* of $f$ at $a \in A$ is the set
  $$
  \partial f(a)=\left\{x^* \in X^* \mid f(x) - f(a) \ge \langle x^*, x-a \rangle \text { for each } x \in A\right\}.
  $$
  The elements of $\partial f(a)$ are called *subgradients* of $f$ at $a$.

> **Theorem:** Assume $A$ is open convex and $f$ convex. For $a\in A$ and $x^* \in X^*$, the following assertions are equivalent:
>
> - (i) $x^* \in \partial f(a)$;
> - (ii) $x^*(v) \leq f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$ for each $v \in X$;
> - (iii) $f_-^{\prime}(a)[v] \leq x^*(v) \leq f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$ for each $v \in X$.

As a corollary, we obtain that $\partial f(a)$ is fully determined by the values of $f$ in any neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, we use $x^*(v)$ and $\langle x^*, v \rangle$ interchangeably. Notice that $f'_-(a)[v] = -f'_+(a)[-v]$, so (ii) is equivalent to (iii).

Let's prove (i) implies (ii). Let $x^* \in \partial f(a)$, i.e.,
$$
f(x)-f(a) \ge \langle x^*, x-a \rangle \quad \forall x\in A.
$$
Then $f(a+tv)-f(a) \ge t\langle x^*, v \rangle$ and thus
$$
\frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t} \ge \langle x^*, v \rangle \quad \forall t>0.
$$
The claim then follows by taking the limit $t \to 0^+$.

Let's prove (ii) implies (i). Notice that $f$ is convex, so the map
$$
\varphi:(0, +\infty) \to \mathbb R, t \mapsto \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t}
$$
is increasing. Assume $\langle x^*, v \rangle \le f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$ for each $v \in X$. Then $\langle x^*, v \rangle \le \varphi (t)$ for all $t>0$. We pick $t=1$ and $v=x-a$. Then
$$
\langle x^*, x-a \rangle \le \frac{f(a+1(x-a))-f(a)}{1}.
$$
This completes the proof.