# Assume $A$ is open convex and $f$ convex continuous. Then $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $a \in A$ if and only if $\partial f (a)$ is a singleton

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

---

Let $A$ be a subset of a normed space $X$ and $f:A \to \mathbb R$.

- Let $a \in \operatorname{int} A$. For $v \in X$, the *right directional* derivative $f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$, the *left directional* derivative $f_{-}^{\prime}(a)[v]$, and the (*bilateral*) directional derivative $f^{\prime}(a)[v]$ are defined by:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t} \\
  f_{-}^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0^-} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t} \\
  f^{\prime}(a)[v] &= \lim _{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+t v)-f(a)}{t}.
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  We say that $f$ is *Gâteaux differentiable* at $a$ if $f^{\prime}(a) \in X^{*}$.
- The *subdifferential* of $f$ at $a \in A$ is the set
  $$
  \partial f(a)=\left\{x^* \in X^* \mid f(x) - f(a) \ge \langle x^*, x-a \rangle \text { for each } x \in A\right\}.
  $$
  The elements of $\partial f(a)$ are called *subgradients* of $f$ at $a$.

> **Theorem:** Assume $A$ is open convex and $f$ convex continuous. Then $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $a \in A$ if and only if $\partial f (a)$ is a singleton. In this case, $\partial f (a) = \{f'(a)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the following lemmas

> [Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478530/characterize-subdifferential-of-a-convex-function-by-directional-derivative) Assume $A$ is open convex and $f$ convex. For $a\in A$ and $x^* \in X^*$, the following assertions are equivalent:
>
> - (i) $x^* \in \partial f(a)$;
> - (ii) $x^*(v) \leq f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$ for each $v \in X$;
> - (iii) $f_-^{\prime}(a)[v] \leq x^*(v) \leq f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$ for each $v \in X$.

> [Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4465343/let-a-be-an-open-convex-subset-of-a-normed-space-if-fa-to-mathbb-r-is-co) Assume $A$ is open convex and $f$ convex continuous at $a\in A$. If $f^{\prime}(a) [v]$ exists finite for all $v \in X$, then $f$ is Gâteaux differentiable at $a$.

> [Lemma 3:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478549/characterize-directional-derivative-of-a-convex-continuous-function-by-subdiffer) Assume $A$ is open convex and $f$ convex continuous. For $a\in A$ and $v\in X$,
> $$
> f'_+(a)[v] = \max_{x^* \in \partial f (a)} \langle x^*, v \rangle.
> $$

By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4477191/continuous-convex-function-on-a-normed-vector-space-has-non-empty-subdifferentia) result, $\partial f (a) \neq \emptyset$. Let $x^* \in \partial f (a)$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4465343/let-a-be-an-open-convex-subset-of-a-normed-space-if-fa-to-mathbb-r-is-co) result, $f'_+(a)[v]$ exists finite for all $v\in X$.

Let $f$ be Gâteaux differentiable at $a$. By **Lemma 1**, $f_-^{\prime}(a)[v] \leq x^*(v) \leq f_{+}^{\prime}(a)[v]$ and thus $f^{\prime}(a)[v] \leq x^*(v) \leq f^{\prime}(a)[v]$ for each $v \in X$. This implies $f'(a) = x^*$.

Let $\partial f (a)$ be a singleton. By **Lemma 2**, it suffices to show that $f'_+(a)[v] = f'_-(a)[v]$. This is indeed true from the fact that $f'_-(a)[v] =-f'_+(a)[-v]$ and **Lemma 3**.